# Unsaved documents being stored to iCloud

Tags: icloud

I have just discovered to my horror that unsaved documents from Textedit and Pages are being stored on Apple's iCloud servers.

This is absolutely not ok and I need to turn it off, how can I do this?

Comment: What exactly did you observe that makes you think this? What Mac/iPad/phone model are you using, and what OS version?

Comment: I observed the files in the iCloud drive folders for Textedit and Pages.

Comment: This is on the latest OSX desktop.

Comment: Apparently this has been a "feature" since Yosemite, I knew nothing about it and can't find an up-to-date fix.

Comment: Please describe what happened. What are the names of the files? Normally, unsaved files are kept within your Library folder, in "Application Saved State", as far as I know. Where did you leanr that this has been a feature since Yosemite?

Comment: They are just called Untitled, Untitled 2 etc, they are files that I have never saved just opened and assumed were being cached on my HD. If you Google the heading of this question you will see the results about Yosemite.

Comment: The first search result I got points to a Macworld article about this which refers to https://mjtsai.com/blog/2014/10/26/yosemite-uploads-unsaved-documents-and-recent-addresses-to-icloud/. Did you try the solution described there?

Comment: Well I have decided not to take the risk of been subject to any further key logging attacks by Apple and have turned iCloud off completely.

Comment: Storing draft documents in iCloud has nothing to do with key logging. If somebody (be it Apple, be it another party) wanted to capture all your keystrokes, there would be simpler (and less easy to detect) ways to do so.

Comment: Even if this were true (and I don't think we've ascertained that it is), millions of people store private documents in iCloud, which has end-to-end encryption, which not even Apple can access. See this document for details. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202303

Answer (score 2):

As you may know, apps like TextEdit and Pages save every document to disk, automatically, as soon as it is created.

However, iCloud is many things. There is "Desktop and Documents", in which those folders are automatically synced to iCloud.

There are also individual 'container' folders for apps on iCloud - required for iOS/iPadOS apps.

The only issue is that Apple's apps save documents to their iCloud folders by default. (If you actually do Command S to choose a location, you will see that iCloud comes up first.)

It may be the case that this default is causing the auto-save files to save to the cloud as well.

This is easily remedied, simply by disabling iCloud as the default location for these apps:

```
defaults write NSGlobalDomain NSDocumentSaveNewDocumentsToCloud -bool false
```

You could also disable each app's iCloud folder in System Settings, though it may have uses. This would still retain the general functionality of iCloud Drive.

Note that you can turn on end-to-end encryption for iCloud Drive so that only you can access your documents. Apple would not have the keys.
[iCloud data security overview](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202303)

It would make the front pages if it were discovered that Apple (or any government) could access your data.

Comment: iCloud Drive does not use end-to-end encryption by default, the user must manually turn it on. In default settings, Apple could access a users iCloud files.

Comment: Clearly I mean unsaved by the user, how do you not understand that? Thanks for your answer which I will accept if you remove the condescending tone from it. I have been blocked from asking questions on this site now, why? My question is perfectly legitimate and should be of great importance to others. Sorry it embarrasses Apple!

Comment: @Appalling You have to remember that I don't know what you know (or indeed anyone else who comes here, looking for answers to a similar problem). It's therefore important to be accurate and specific about terms. No disrespect was intended.

Comment: You and others in this question have been trying to belittle my very serious concerns, I have worked professionally in IT for over 20 years. Now I am banned from asking questions on this site because one of you has reported my alleged "bad questions". It is childlike fanboy behaviour plain and simple.